# How can i link the javaScript file?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a calculator using JavaScript.I tried to display the value '0' in the screen,but it doesn't working.Can i know why is that ?

My js file

```
const calculator = {
  displayValue: '0';firstOperand: null;waitingForSecondOperand: false;operator: null;
}

function updateDisplay() {
  const display = document.querySelector('.calculator-dipalay');
  display.value = calculator.displayValue;
}

updateDisplay();
```

my HTML code

```
</html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <script src="myscript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="calculator">

    <input type="text" class="calculator-dipalay" value="" disabled/>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `const calculator` object is incorrect format.

Comment: Include your script at the end of your body. You are currently trying to access an element ('calculator-dipalay') that has not yet been loaded.

Comment: add script file after used selector elements or you should learn more about onload events if you are executing code before selectors

Comment: try putting your script tag as the last thing in your body tag. the JS file is probably getting called before your html is finished loading

Comment: i guess `document.querySelector('.calculator-dipalay')` is returning an array and afterwards you try to set the value to that array instead of setting it to the items inside it

Comment: @messerbill — No. `querySelector` returns either an element or null. It never returns an array (nor does it return any kind of array-like object). You are probably confusing it for `querySelectorAll`.

Comment: Aside from the problem described in the duplicate, you have some basic syntax errors. Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the console. Read the error messages.

Comment: @Quentin is right....like always :D https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Comment: @jtylerm your idea was worked for me.Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace ; by , for constant  and you must move `<script src="myscript.js"></script>` before `</body>` tag.

```
</html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="calculator">
    <input type="text" class="calculator-dipalay" value="" disabled/>
  </div>
  <script src="myscript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
const calculator={
```

And update:

```
    displayValue: '0',
    firstOperand: null, 
    waitingForSecondOperand: false,
    operator: null }
```

```js
const calculator={ 
displayValue: '0',
firstOperand: null, 
waitingForSecondOperand: false,
operator: null }

function updateDisplay(){ 
const display = document.querySelector('.calculator-dipalay'); 
display.value = calculator.displayValue; 
}

updateDisplay();
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="style.css" >
      <script src="myscript.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>

      <div class="calculator">

      <input type="text" class="calculator-dipalay" value="" disabled/>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This appears to fix the problem because you're running the code in a snippet on this page, but it doesn't.  The real problem (other than the syntax problem you've highlighted) is that the script runs *before* the DOM is ready, so ` document.querySelector('.calculator-dipalay')` returns undefined.

Comment: @Archer you are correct, it returns as undefined.how should i solve the issue?

Comment: you need move <script src="myscript.js"></script> to the before </body> tag to ensure all tags are loaded

Comment: @Archer I updated the answer

Comment: I replaced it and it works. can i know how it happens? whats is the issue if i placed within head tag?

Comment: because html page load tags from top to bottom

Comment: so we need to place the script tag for JS file at the end of body tag all the time,is it?

Comment: yes, put script to before end of body tag is a good practice

Comment: okay thank you so much for the favor